# Twitter API: what is the difference between `name` and `screen_name`? Which one is a url username?

Tags: api, twitter

I need a username token that represents a url `username`, like here `=>` `https://twitter.com/username`.

Twitter [API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/entities-in-twitter-objects#user_mentions) aren't clear on that. I can't tell the difference:

> screen_name = The user screen name
>
> name = The user full name

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Screen name is the username of the twitter account.

From the twitter account you can see  this [url](https://twitter.com/TwitterEng)

```
 "user_mentions": [{
      "screen_name": "TwitterEng",
      "name": "Twitter Engineering",
      "id": 6844292,
      "id_str": "6844292",
      "indices": [81, 92]
    }, {
```

There is also a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-screen-name) available for extracting `screen_name`